# Deletions with Spring data/Hibernate: ORA-01407: Cannot update to Null

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

I am trying to delete rows in a certain table from my database using the `deleteAll()` method in the [CRUD Repository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html)

When I do so I get this error relating to my DOG table, row DOG_OWNER:

```
ORA-01407: Cannot update DOG_OWNER to Null
```

Is the fix just to remove the `not-null constraint` on this row, or is there another workaround?

Comment: Add your related entities and the code that perform the `deleteAll` operation

Comment: if `DOG_OWNER` is not nullable, you should remove referenced `DOG` entries as well

Comment: DOG_OWNER is the row, I am trying to delete rows in the DOG table

Comment: If you have the sql printing setup for the hibernate in the logs, could you please update your question with the sql that is in the logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below a simplified scenario with a `FOREIGN KEY`not NULLable and with a constraint using `ON DELETE SET NULL`, which leads to the reported error after delete of the **referenced key**.

In this case indeed helps to lift the `NOT NULL`constraint on the foreign key.

```
create table dog_owner 
(id number);
alter table dog_owner add  primary key (id);
insert into dog_owner values (1);

create table dog 
(id number,
dog_owner_id number not null); -- foreign key is not nullable ..
alter table dog add  primary key (id);
alter table dog add  foreign key (dog_owner_id) references dog_owner(id) 
ON DELETE SET NULL; -- but the contrains sets is to null...

insert into dog values (1,1);
commit;

delete from dog_owner where id = 1;

-- SQL-Fehler: ORA-01407: cannot update ("SCHEMA_NAME"."DOG"."DOG_OWNER_ID") to NULL 

alter table dog modify (dog_owner_id number  null);

delete from dog_owner where id = 1;

-- 1 rows deleted
```